# Mutable access to two nodes in petgraph

Tags: graph, rust, dataflow, petgraph

I am using the [petgraph](https://github.com/bluss/petgraph/) crate to implement a dataflow graph. I would like to copy data from an edge source node to its target node. For that I would need a mutable reference to the target node and an immutable reference to the source node. However Rust's borrow checker prevents that from happening since both a mutable and immutable reference is taken to the graph at the same time.

Is there a function available in petgraph that provides mutable references to multiple nodes at the same time?

Comment: How about [index_twice_mut](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.3/petgraph/graph/struct.Graph.html#method.index_twice_mut) ?

Comment: Thank you, should have seen that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`index_twice_mut`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/latest/petgraph/graph/struct.Graph.html#method.index_twice_mut) method is the way to do that.

Note that it panics if you try to index the same object twice, so you need to check that first.